# get id value from req.body.id for new value of object

Tags: javascript, json, express, prisma

I have a field with id value in it. It auto created while created a new data. Concatenated with string. I have doing a try, but it gets `undefined` value.

1. code:

```
const { id, nm_acara, tugas, nm_petugas } = req.body;

const result = await prisma.dinas.create({
  data: {
    kd_dinas: `D-${id}`,
    nm_acara,
    tugas,
    nm_petugas,
    rundown: "/texts/" + req.file.filename,
    },
});
```

2. result:
   [image: result]

Comment: I think, in case of create id will be undefined,

Comment: Please paste you request screenshot, to help us understand request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you sure you sent the id property to the server? or was it just created by the ORM?

Comment: created automatically with ORM

Comment: @FebryAryo you cannot use id when it was created by with ORM, you must send it with the client to the server and then get it in req.body

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is correct

But likely `id` was not sent properly

So, u should check the existence of id firstly

```js
const { id, nm_acara, tugas, nm_petugas } = req.body;

console.log(id) // print the id
```

If `id` still `undefined` => this issue occurs in client side

Comment: I just use postman for testing, it still undefined

Answer (score 0):

make sure are you using the below lines for parsing `application/json!`?

```
  app.use(express.json());
  app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));
```

console.log the `req.body` for check are you getting id or not.

Comment: I already add it in my app